# Function arguments within a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, reference, structure

I have the following code:

```
include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct foo{
    int x;
}Foo;

void funcY(Foo *f1)
{
    printf("%d", f1.x);
}

void funcX(Foo *f1)
{
    printf("%d", f1.x);
    funcY(f1);            <---- is this correct?
}

int main()
{
    Foo *foo1 = (struct foo *)malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    foo1.x = 10;
    funcX(foo1); 
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know exactly how to label this problem. What is the best way for me to approach this?

Comment: What is the intended behavior?  Does it work as intended?  What happens when you try to compile and run it, and how is that different from what you want?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> funcY(f1);            <---- is this correct?
> ```

Yes, this particular line is correct. However, several other parts that aren't: specifically, accessing `struct` members by pointer needs `->` operator, rather than a dot:

```
printf("%d", f1->x);
```

Another small issue is that one should not cast `malloc` in C:

```
Foo *foo1 = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
```

Finally, you are missing a call to `free(foo)` to deallocate `malloc`-ed memory. Note that you do not have to use `malloc` - allocate the `struct` in the automatic store, and use `&` to access its address:

```
int main()
{
    Foo foo1;
    foo1.x = 10;
    funcX(&foo1); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was in a rush and didn't catch my errors.

Answer (score 0):

`funcY(f1)` is correct - it passes the `Foo` pointer to `funcY`, and since `funcY` accepts a `Foo` pointer we can assume it'll work as intended.

`printf("%d", f1.x);`, however, is not correct. `f1` is a `Foo` pointer, not a `Foo`. To access it's `x` field you need to derefer it first - `(*f1).x` - or use the sytactic sugar `f1->x`.